# How to create AWS API Gateway Custom Domain using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a Custom Domain for an API Gateway,
I already have my SSL imported in ACM.

I am trying to run the following template,
**But I'm getting an error -**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: Test Custom Domain

Resources:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
  Properties: 
    CertificateArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:acm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:certificate/xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx'
    DomainName: 'test-api.example.com'
    EndpointConfiguration: 
      Types: 
        - 'EDGE'
```

**Error -**

```
Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Structure of the SAM template is invalid. All 'Resources' must be Objects. If you're using YAML, this may be an indentation issue.. Rollback requested by user.
```

**Reference -**>
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-domainname.html

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you what the issue is. You are using YAML but your indentation is incorrect.

To resolve your issue, fix the indentation of the `Properties` attributes, to be indented one tab further than the `Type` and `Properties` attributes.

Comment: Hi, still getting the same error, updated the template that I'm trying to run

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the missing logicalId,
Every resource to be created needs to fall under a logicalId -

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: Test Custom Domain

Resources:
  test:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
    Properties: 
      CertificateArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:acm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:certificate/xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx'
      DomainName: 'test-api.example.com'
      EndpointConfiguration: 
        Types: 
          - 'EDGE'
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'` means that you are creating a SAM template rather than a pure CloudFormation template.

I do not believe `DomainName` exists in SAM.  Instead, you should assign it straight to your API:

```
Resources:
  YourApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Domain:
        DomainName: test-api.example.com
        CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east:your-cert
        EndpointConfiguration: EDGE
```